# Find a statement that is true in one of the structures and false in the other.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Find a statement that is true in one of the structures and false in the other.

> $a)$ $\langle \Bbb N,<\rangle $ and $\langle \Bbb N,\{(n,n+1):n\in\Bbb N\}\rangle$

**Try:** I have not been able to find the statement that is true in one and false in the other. I have tried for example with this,
$\forall x\exists y(x<y\Rightarrow \exists z(x<z<y))$, this is not fulfilled in the one of the successor because there are no naturals between n and n+1 but I don't know about the other one.

Because I can only do the statement with the order relation I can't use additions or anything. Because I had the following in mind: $\forall x\forall y(x<y\Rightarrow y=x+1)$. This last one is fulfilled in the structure of the successor but not in the natural ones with the usual order, but as I said I cannot use sums. Some help.

Comment: Did you previously post this question? I’m pretty sure I’ve seen it before, but I can’t find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second relation is not transitive.

Comment: For OP, hint for writing this: start with $\forall x\forall y\forall z$ (or, same thing, $\forall x,y,z$)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (in addition to the selected answer): with the second relation, for every $x$, there is exactly one $y$ such that $x<y$. That is, $\forall x,y,z,(x<y\land x<z)\Rightarrow (y=z)$.

A third: *trichotomy*. With the first relation, for any $x$ and $y$, either $x<y$, $x=y$, or $y<x$.

Comment: That last one could be phrased as either $\forall x\forall y$ or $\exists x\forall y$.